# Applying datetime manupulations on columns parsed from Quickbase to get correct datetime format in pyspark databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting the date from Quickbase in the format "1609372800000". Now I know the code on how to convert this into the correct date format.
Code is

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1609372800000/1000.0)
date = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Now I want to apply this calculation to a column of pyspark dataframe.
I tried using this code but is giving me the error that

> Expecting integer but received col type

```
df.withColumn("product_availability_due_date",col("product_availability_due_date").cast('int'))
df.withColumn('product_availability_due_date_1',datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(col('product_availability_due_date')/1000.0).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

**product_availability_due_date**- this column datatype is string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `from_unixtime` to do the conversion:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'product_availability_due_date_1', 
    F.from_unixtime((F.col('product_availability_due_date').cast('long') / 1000))
)

df2.show()
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+
|product_availability_due_date|product_availability_due_date_1|
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+
|                1609372800000|            2020-12-31 00:00:00|
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+
```